# Vim: enclose word in tag

Tags: vim

I would like to wrap a word in Vim with enclosing tags, such as from `word` to `'word'` or from `word` to `(word)`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use Tim Pope's [vim-surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround), you can use: `ysw'` to enclose a word with "`", `ysw(` to surround the word with "(". If you want to surround the word with an actual tag such as the HTML tag `<code>`, you can use `yswt`, then type in your tag in the prompt. If you want to change existing surround elements, use `csw`, type in the surround element you want to replace and hit `<CR> (enter)`, and type the new surrounding element.

Note that for the commands above to work, you have to put the cursor in the beginning of the word you want to surround.

From its official page:

> Press `cs"'` (that's c, s, double quote, single quote) inside
>
> "Hello world!"
>
> to change it to
>
> 'Hello world!'
>
> Now press `cs'<q>` to change it to
>
> Hello world!
>
> To go full circle, press `cat"` to get
>
> "Hello world!"
>
> To remove the delimiters entirely, press `ds"` .
>
> Hello world!
>
> Now with the cursor on "Hello", press `ysiw]` (`iw` is a text object).
>
> [Hello] world!
>
> Let's make that braces and add some space (use "}" instead of "{" for no space): `cs]{`
>
> { Hello } world!
>
> Now wrap the entire line in parentheses with `yssb` or `yes)` .
>
> ({ Hello } world!)
>
> Revert to the original text: `ds{ds)`
>
> Hello world!
>
> Emphasize hello: `ysiw<em>`
>
> *Hello* world!
>
> Finally, let's try out visual mode. Press a capital `V` (for linewise visual mode) 
>   followed by `S<p class="important">`.
>
> *Hello* world!

For more detailed usage info, install `vim-surround`, and then use `:help surround` to invoke the docs.

Comment: As a side-note, non-capital V will let you select any number of characters (useful for figures like 1.10 where "iw" would either select 1 or 10).

Comment: Nice answer.  I write about this with Linux in an Issue on the `vim-surround` GitHub repo, updated with an example of HTML tagging, including animated GIF demo: https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround/issues/117#issuecomment-272007689

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at Tim Pope's [surround.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697).

Answer (score 4):

`<c-r>` is very handy for these, letting you insert the contents of a register, the clipboard, the word under the cursor (`<c-r><c-a>`), etc. For instance:

```
nmap <space>' ciw'<c-r>"'<esc>
vmap <space>' c'<c-r>"'<esc>
nmap <space>( ciw(<c-r>")<esc>
vmap <space>( c(<c-r>")<esc>
```

Which maps `space+'` to wrap the current word or visual selection in single quotes, or `space+(` to wrap the current word or visual selection in double quotes.

The content of the mapping means "change inner word|selected text, insert quote, insert the word, insert quote, exit insert mode".

Answer (score 3):

I use this snippet to record a macro into the letter M for the first time:
qmcw'<c-r>" '<esc>q 
Then redo it with @m

Explanation, at first 10 strikes are necessary:

- qm begins to record the macro in the letter m
- cw change only a word and put you into the insert mode
- ' writes the first quote
- <c-r>" paste the word that we erased at stade 2 while staying into
  the insert mode
- ' is the other surrounding quote
- <esc> go back to the edit word
- q end the macro.

Recall it with @m : now we only use two strikes to surround...

Answer (score 0):

In **NVIM** you can use this function and map `<leader>sw` or `<leader>sW` to use `:lua Surround("w")` and `:lua Surround("W")` respectively, where `Surround` is a custom function.

You can find more information and the function definition [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77027791/22487812).