# How to modify the following VIM regex to work with white space after commas?

Tags: regex, vim

I took this regex from this question: [What Vim command(s) can be used to quote/unquote words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147875/what-vim-commands-can-be-used-to-quote-unquote-words)

```
:%s/\([^,]\+\)/"\1"/g
```

It turns this:

```
foo,foo bar,bar@foo,foo# bar,bar$ foo#
```

into this:

```
"foo","foo bar","bar@foo","foo# bar","bar$ foo#"
```

I would like to modify the regex to work with this:

```
foo, foo bar ,bar@foo ,foo# bar, bar$ foo#
```

turning it into this:

```
"foo", "foo bar", "bar@foo", "foo# bar", "bar$ foo#"
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work

```
:%s/\s*\([^,]\+\)/ "\1"/g | %s/^ //
```

Match all the leading whitespace before putting it into the capture group. Then put a space before the capture group in quotes. This will put and extra space in the first column so you need to remove that space we use the second substitute command.