# In vim How Do I Put a Character Before and After a Word

Tags: vim

In vim, what is the character command sequence to put the same character before and after a word.  I think there's a way to do it but I forget.

Say I have the word `candy` and I want to make it `=candy=`. Isn't there command sequence to do this more efficiently than entering insert mode twice?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147875/what-vim-commands-can-be-used-to-quote-unquote-words

Comment: The surround.vim plugin if you're open to plugins, via `ysiw=` to surround the "inner word"

Comment: `s/\w\+/=&=/` or `s/candy/=&=/`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a plugin called [tpope/vim-surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) that makes this easier. In your case, it would be `ysiw=` (or `ysw=` if you're at the beginning of the word). This plugin also supplies convenient mappings for deleting and changing surrounding characters. In my opinion, this is one of those *essential vim plugins*. I can't imagine not installing it.

However, if you don't want to install a plugin, the shortest approach I'm aware of would be

```
ciw==<esc>P
```

This is one keystroke shorter than

```
bi=<esc>ea=<esc>
```